# How to substring <img src="myimage" /> from a string?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I take an < img tag from string? Sample string is given below. But too bad name and surname parts are dynamic and sometimes image names are numbers...

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <img src='http://www.mydomain.com/images/name_surname.jpg' /> Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
```

What I've tried so far:

```
sMyText.Substring(sDescription.IndexOf("<img"), count?!);
```

how to count the who image character length? This is where I fail. Please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regular expressions.

```
string sMyText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <img src='http://www.mydomain.com/images/name_surname.jpg' /> Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.";

Match match = Regex.Match(sMyText, "<img[^>]+>");

if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Answer (score 4):

I really don't like parsing html with a regex (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/352176)). I'd suggest using something like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It may seem overkill for your example but you'll save yourself a lot of pain in the future!

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
var links = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img");
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using LINQ:

```
string s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <img src='http://www.mydomain.com/images/name_surname.jpg' /> Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.";

string img = new string(s.SkipWhile(c => c != '<').TakeWhile(c => c != '>').Concat(">".ToCharArray()).ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(img); // output: <img src='http://www.mydomain.com/images/name_surname.jpg' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use simple regex:

```
(?=\<)(.*?)(?<=\>)
```

http://regex101.com/r/cD0cT0